# Meteor 'reset password' and 'verification' emails: the clicked link restarts the app in new window

Tags: meteor

For both 'SendVerificationEmail()' and 'sendResetPasswordEmail()' - once the email that is sent is clicked, a new instance of the application is opened in another window.  I don't want this to happen.  I just want to continue from where the 'sends' originated.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean when the link in the email is clicked, it opens a new window(/tab)?  I don't think there is a way to stop this.  Isn't this how all web apps work with email verification links?  I don't believe meteor is unique in this regard.

Comment: But here's the user who initiates the process in one window and a response comes up in another, now with both windows open.  Not the best user experience.  All I can think of doing is instructing the user to close the new window and continue from the first window where they left off.  Any other ideas?  How do people handle this scenario?